# C++ shared_ptr - attach to a new raw pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, pointers, shared-ptr

I think I'm missing something simple here. I'm using Boost's `shared_ptr`.

```
shared_ptr<Foo> pA(new Foo()); 
shared_ptr<Foo> pB(new Foo());
```

Now, I want to switch `pB` so it contains the contents of `pA`, decrementing the ref count of `pB`. How can I do this?

Comment: "Boost's `std::tr1::shared_ptr`" is a bit weird, don't you think? :) Boost has `boost::shared_ptr`, TR1 has `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, and C++0x has `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Boost also contains a TR1 Library which includes shared_ptr it resolves std::tr1::shared_ptr to the native std::shared_ptr of the c++ lib, or if such doesn't exist to boost::shared_ptr. So boost's std::tr1::shared_ptr is valid and meanigful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all done automatically:

```
pB = pA;  // pB ref count is decrement (in this case causing the value to be released)
          // pB is then made to point at the same value as pA
          // Thus incrementing the refCount.
```